# Oracle Creating an ER-model via procedure

Tags: oracle, model

I have to get data about specific tables and I wrote a procedure for that.
Everything works fine, but I asked myself if it is possible to let Oracle create an ER-model via SQL-code.

Because in the developer you can click on a table and in the opening window you can click on model an get an ER-model of your table and related tables.

I am using Oracle 11g R2.

I have already tried to figure out how this works via Google but did not get any answers that could help.

Thank you.

Comment: We don't have a PL/SQL api for generating models/diagrams, because all of that code in the client itself. Additionally today, we don't have a CLI for the app, so you're left to do what you're doing now - using your mouse.

Comment: OK, thank you. @thatjeffsmith